# Were boolean logic used in the analog computers?

Tags: computer-architecture, circuits

I began a simple collection of the events behind todays computers. My knowledege in these fields is so limited, and I read:

"In the 1930s and working independently, American electronic engineer Claude Shannon and Soviet logician Victor Shestakov both showed a one-to-one correspondence between the concepts of Boolean logic and certain electrical circuits, now called logic gates, which are now ubiquitous in digital computers.[70] They showed[71] that electronic relays and switches can realize the expressions of Boolean algebra. This thesis essentially founded practical digital circuit design."

from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_computing_hardware#Digital_computation

I wonder if it's correct to say that "bools law were not used in the analog computers" (the early computers).

Greetings

Comment: Perhaps [retrocomputing.se]?

Comment: What does "use [Boolean logic]" mean exactly? The question is vague. This is essentially just asking for definitions of digital & analog computing.

Comment: I mean, are logic gates used in a analog computer

Comment: Also, were there any programming using if-statements in analog computers(?)